# .refreshable continues to further NavigationStack views - how to stop it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, refreshable

I have set a .refreshable modifier on one of my views (attached to a VStack). This view has NavigationLinks to other pages, but unexpectedly the refreshable still works in the next pages on the NavigationStack.

i.e. I can still pull to refresh in any page that was linked from the first page where I declared the .refreshable...

I would like this .refreshable to apply only to the first page, and not to the rest of the pages.

How do I do that, and why does it behave like that in the first place?

The code on the first View/page looks like this:

```
 VStack {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            //Some code with list elements
        }
    }
}
.refreshable {
    await vm.loadUserStories(getUrl: url)
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: ok, added a bit of sample code

Comment: How can I use that to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2):

16.4 will fix this bug

> Fixed: Refreshable modifiers applied to lists will no longer also
> apply to lists or scroll views within the content of that list.
> Re-apply a refreshable modifier to the content of the list if this is
> desired behavior. (102052575)

[iOS & iPadOS 16.4 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-16_4-release-notes)

Comment: So its a bug, good to know its not just me. Cool, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [`.refreshable` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/refreshable(action:)):

> Apply this modifier to a view to set the `refresh` value in the view’s environment to a `RefreshAction` instance that uses the specified action as its handler.

So the modifier puts your closure into the SwiftUI environment. That's why all your pages use it.

Reading on:

> For example, when you apply this modifier on iOS and iPadOS to a `List`, the list enables a standard pull-to-refresh gesture that refreshes the list contents.

So the answer is, put the modifier directly on the `List` instead of on the `NavigationStack`. Then only the environment of the `List` (and its subviews) will contain the `RefreshAction`, and it won't be visible to your other pages.

```
VStack {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            //Some code with list elements
        }
        .refreshable {
            await vm.loadUserStories(getUrl: url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to put it first on the List, but my next views are NavigationLinks from within the List, so every new page is still 'refreshable' which I am trying to avoid. So I move it up to the VStack, and it still does that. Isn't there a way to make the refreshable just work for the page its in?

Comment: What is your deployment target? iOS 16? iOS 15?

Comment: It's currently set for 16.0 (would be nice to support 15 as well though)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put the NavigationStack to be the first container not the VStack like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: someView) {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, world!")) {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, world!")) {
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
                
                
            }
            .refreshable {
                print("yes")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

  var someView: some View {
      return VStack {
          List {
              Text("Hello, world!")
              Text("Hello, world!")
          }
      }
  }
 
}
```

this should work, you can use [NavigationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview) if you you want to support iOS versions less than iOS 16 but it's deprecated in iOS 16+

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it but apparently its a bug in iOS